# Vue.js $set not updating the display

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am having trouble using [vuejs 1.0](http://vuejs.org/) $set(), i have made a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6zovax1v/). the `addQty1` works and updates the display, when the `addQty2` only update data.

Any idea why this is happening ?

```js
var TicketLine = Vue.extend({
  template: '#ticketLineTemplate',
  props: ['index', 'lines'],
  data: function() {
    var line = this.lines[this.index];
    return {
      qty: line.qty,
      label: line.label
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addQty1: function() {
      var line = this.lines[this.index];
      line.qty++;
      this.lines.$set(this.index, $.extend({}, line));
    },
    addQty2: function() {
      var line = this.lines[this.index];
      line.qty++;
      this.lines.$set(this.index, line);
    }
  }
});

var lines = [{
  qty: 1,
  label: 'Pizza'
}, {
  qty: 2,
  label: 'Café'
}, {
  qty: 1,
  label: 'Soda'
}];

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    lines: lines
  },
  components: {
    'ticket-line': TicketLine
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="ticket">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template v-for="line in lines">
          <ticket-line :index="$index" :lines="lines"></ticket-line>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script type="text/x-template" id="ticketLineTemplate">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ qty }}</td>
      <td>{{ label }}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="addQty1()">addQty1</button>
        <button type="button" v-on:click="addQty2()">addQty2</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no reason to pass all of the lines to each line as a prop, just pass the current line.  The child components don't need to know all of the lines:

```
<ticket-line  :index="$index" :line="line"></ticket-line>

var TicketLine = Vue.extend({
template: '#ticketLineTemplate',
props : ['index', 'line'],
data: function() {
    return {
        qty: this.line.qty,
        label: this.line.label
    };
},
methods: {
    addQty1: function() {
        this.qty++;
    }
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6zovax1v/1/

As for why you are having this issue, read "Change Detection Caveats" for info http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html .

Edit: Objects are not watched deeply.  So when you update the objects `qty` property, and then `$set` the object, Vue says "OK, this is the same object it was before, no need to update anything".  When you create a new object, Vue is seeing a new object and knows it needs to update.

<s>I believe you could use `$set` directly on the property of the item which should trigger the update</s>:

```
addQty1: function() {
        var qty = this.lines[this.index].qty;
        qty++;
        this.lines[this.index].$set('qty',qty);
        );
    },
```

Edit 2: after testing, that code isn't working for me.  I think the best solution for you here is to refactor your structure so that each line is a component that only knows about itself.  I know you said there are reasons for this in your app but there should be another solution that is more appropriate.  Components shouldn't need to know the whole array, that's the idea of components.  You can use `.sync` or event broadcasting if they need to interact.  Anyway sorry I couldn't get the code working, hope you solve this.

Comment: Am passing all the lines for specific reasons that are out of the scope of this topic, i have read the reactivity guide that you linked me and still dont get it, $set() is suposed trigger the change detection. am i missing somehing ?

Comment: see edit - `$set` on the object won't trigger a change, but `$set` on the `qty` property will

Comment: Yes it still not working maybe the structure need to change. will aprove yours if no other solution is found, thank you @Jeff